# No quesito vector de pair<string, int>: Ao adicionar uma nova string, verificar se uma futura string tem mesmo valor de uma string já adicionada

Tags: array, c++, comparação

E se tiver, mudar o valor do par anteriormente adicionado ao invés de adicionar um par novo.

Então, eu gostaria de adicionar pares string, int em um vetor, só que, para evitar pares redundantes, verificar se a string já existe e ao invés de adicionar um valor duplicado no vetor, atualizar um já existente. A intenção é armazenar o nome e a pontuação de um jogador. Qual a melhor maneira? É possível?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define psi pair<string, int> 
#define mp make_pair

using namespace std;

int numround(int&);
void validate(string, int);


int main(){
int n, score = 0;
string name = "";
vector<psi> v;

numround(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

    cout << "Enter name[32] and score[-1000 ~ 1000]: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cin >> score;
    validate(name, score);
    v.push_back(mp(name,score)); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível trabalhar sim com vector, mas a busca iria ser linear. Porém com map você está utilizando Arvores Rubro-Negras, que permite uma busca mais rápida de pares já inseridos.

```
std::map<std::string,int> pontuacao;
```

para inserir basta

```
std::map<std::string,int>::iterator busca = pontuacao.find(name);
if(busca != pontuacao.end()){
    busca->second = score;
} else {
    pontuacao.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(name, score));
}
```

fonte e exemplos:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/